# How can I get a screen to reflect a new record created in the BLC / Code?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have BLC code to create a new record (from an imported file) in a custom screen, but I'd like to get the screen to automatically navigate to that new record.  After creating the record and persisting, I've tried to use

```
<view>.Current = <new cache>;
<view>.View.RequestRefresh();
```

But that doesn't seem to do it.

Is there a snippet of code that will take a newly created record in code, after persisted, and make that the record displayed on the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a graph object, set the current = the record you want and execute a

```
throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, null);
```

Comment: That did the trick - thanks much Patrick! ;D